# Flutter unable to retrieve the screen data passed from one screen to another

Tags: android, flutter

I have a form that serves both the 'Add' and 'Edit' functionalities. When I pass the data to another screen to perform edits, I'm receiving empty values(i,e getting empty object for both scenarios). Could anyone assist me with this issue? i.e, i am using same screen to handle "Add" and "Edit".

```
class ScreenAddBeneficiary extends StatefulWidget {
  final BeneficiaryDTOList? screenData;
  ScreenAddBeneficiary({Key? key,  this.screenData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenAddBeneficiaryNewState createState() =>
      _ScreenAddBeneficiaryNewState(screenData);
}

class _ScreenAddBeneficiaryNewState extends State {
  late final BeneficiaryDTOList beneficiaryDataForEdit;

  _ScreenAddBeneficiaryNewState(BeneficiaryDTOList? fx4uBeneficiaryData)
      : beneficiaryDataForEdit =
      fx4uBeneficiaryData ?? BeneficiaryDTOList();



  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (beneficiaryDataForEdit != null &&
        beneficiaryDataForEdit is BeneficiaryDTOList) {
      Log(“Prefetch data>>>${beneficiaryDataForEdit.toJson()}");
    }
  }

}
```

And passing the data from another screen is,

```
{
  customerId: 4344654,
  beneficiaryType: "FGG",
  beneId: 40120,
  loginuserid: R4344654
}
```

Below is the pojo class,

```
class FetchBeneficiaryPojo {
  Data? data;

  FetchBeneficiaryPojo({this.data});

  FetchBeneficiaryPojo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  List<BeneficiaryDTOList>? beneficiaryDTOList;

  Data({this.beneficiaryDTOList});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['beneficiaryDTOList'] != null) {
      beneficiaryDTOList = <BeneficiaryDTOList>[];
      json['beneficiaryDTOList'].forEach((v) {
        beneficiaryDTOList!.add(new BeneficiaryDTOList.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.beneficiaryDTOList != null) {
      data['beneficiaryDTOList'] =
          this.beneficiaryDTOList!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class BeneficiaryDTOList {
  String? customerId;
  String? beneficiaryType;
  String? beneId;

  BeneficiaryDTOList({this.customerId, this.beneficiaryType, this.beneId});

  BeneficiaryDTOList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    customerId = json['customerId'];
    beneficiaryType = json['beneficiaryType'];
    beneId = json['beneId'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['customerId'] = this.customerId;
    data['beneficiaryType'] = this.beneficiaryType;
    data['beneId'] = this.beneId;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the invocation code as well?

Comment: @Clevino, I have added pojo and sample data passing from another screen. can you please help on this

Comment: That's informative but if you could also ads the code where you push the route  or call `ScreenAddBeneficiary` widget would be helpful.

Comment: internally we were using the custom navigation to move the page

 void navigateTo(
      {required int eventId, dynamic data, bool addToStack = true}) {
    AppController.handleEventStackController(eventId, data, addToStack);
  }

Comment: if you print screenData in initState what is the result? null? Or the map you passing.

Comment: its showing all null values, {customerId: null, beneficiaryType: null, beneId: null}


In the previous screen, just passing data as ''(empty string) for Add data but edit data as passing correctly

Comment: Try this in your code:
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.screenData != null ) {
      Log(“Prefetch data>>>${widget.screenData.toJson()}");
    }
  }

Comment: and let me know the output